# Change standard pitch for midi file playback?

Tags: midi, audacious

It seems that when playing a midi file with audacious a standard pitch of 440hz is applied.

Is it possible to change the standard pitch to say 443hz?

Comment: I am not completely sure I follow what you are after but have a look at: File --> Settings --> Plugins --> Effect --> Sample Rate Converter. Hit the little cog wheel and this might be what you are after?